# Sequence of matrices: finding product and inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$ as $n \to \infty $, where $A_n$  and $B_n$ are invertible square matrices of same order. 
Does there exist any sequence of matrices to converge to $AB$ and $A^{-1}$?

Comment: In what metric do they converge, Euclidean?

Comment: @Adam standard metric. Coordinatewise it should converge.

Comment: Then $A_nB_n$ should converge to $AB$, you see why?

Comment: @Adam explain it a bit

Comment: What makes you think that $A^{-1}$ will exist?  It's easy to construct a sequence of invertible matrices that converges to a singular matrix.

Comment: It's simple. $A_n\to A$ when every element of matrix $A_n$ converges to a corresponding element of matrix $A$. From sequence arithmetic, $A_nB_n$ should converge to $AB$ since multiplication of matrices is just addition and multiplication of numbers

Comment: @Adam ohkay.. what about the inverse?

Comment: If the inverse exists, consider sequence $A_nA^{-2}$

Comment: @BrianBorchers I was trying to solve that if H is a subgroup of a matrix group, then closure of H is also so. And I got to do this using sequence criterion. So I was wondering about how to show the existence of inverse of a matrix, which is a limit of a sequence in H.

Comment: @Adam all the $A_n$ are invertible but I need to show A is so. Please go through the above comment to understand what exactly I want to do

Comment: You should correct your question then

Comment: Well it was given to be a matrix group. Anyway all the matrices are invertible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we have $A_nB_n \to AB$ and $A_n^{-1} \to A^{-1}$.

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the operator norm. Since $(A_n)_n$ converges, it is in particular bounded so there exists $M > 0$ such that $\|A_n\| \le M, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. We have

\begin{align}
\|A_nB_n - AB\| &= \|A_nB_n - A_nB + A_nB - AB\| \\
&\le \|A_n(B_n - B)\| + \|(A_n - A)B\| \\
&\le \|A_n\|\|(B_n - B)\| + \|(A_n - A)\|\|B\| \\
&\le M\|(B_n - B)\| + \|(A_n - A)\|\|B\| \\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0
\end{align}

so $A_nB_n \to AB$.

Pick $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \ge n_0$ we have $\|A_n - A\| \le \frac1{2\|A^{-1}\|}$. For such $n$ we have

$$\|A_n^{-1}\| - \|A^{-1}\| \le \|A_n^{-1} - A^{-1}\| = \|A_n^{-1}(A_n - A)A^{-1}\| \le \|A_n^{-1}\|\|A_n - A\|\|A^{-1}\| \le \frac12\|A_n^{-1}\|$$

so $\|A_n^{-1}\| \le 2\|A^{-1}\|$. Therefore

$$\|A_n^{-1} - A^{-1}\| \le \|A_n^{-1}\|\|A_n - A\|\|A^{-1}\| \le 2\|A^{-1}\|^2\|A_n-A\| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0 $$
so $A_n^{-1} \to A^{-1}$.

Comment: You are assuming $A^{-1}$ exists. Comments from OP seems to imply this is case, but it may be worth to note that there are sequences of invertible matrices which do not converge to an invertible matrix and in particular, the sequence of inverses do not converge at all. Ex: $A_n = \tfrac{1}{n}I$.